# Does xDebug support PHP 5.5?

Tags: php, xdebug

I have a PHP 5.5 version and I want to configure xDebug for it. I've installed a version `2.5.5` of it, but the wizard of xDebug says that `"PHP versions below 7.0 are not supported"`.

So could someone tell me if xDebug supports PHP 5.5? Or should I use another version of xDebug? (Tried 3 different versions).

Comment: Which version of Xdebug are you using? PHP5 support was dropped in version 2.6.0 iirc

Comment: As I said, xDebug version is 2.5.5

Comment: What wizard exactly tells you < 7 is not supported? Does the installation complete and something doesn't work?

Comment: @deceze By the word "wizard" I meant https://xdebug.org/wizard.php Whatever version I install, it still prints that php isn't supported below 7.0

Comment: See the duplicate for the answer. I've opened this issue for you: https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.org/issues/48